# Сортировка в Ruby без использования метода sort

Tags: ruby

Всем доброго времени суток!

В одном из учебных материалов есть задание: *напишите программу, о которой мы говорили в самом начале этой главы, которая просит нас ввести сколько угодно слов 
(по одному слову в строке до тех пор, пока мы не нажмём Enter на пустой строке) и которая затем повторяет нам эти слова в алфавитном порядке.*

Далее есть дополнительное задание: *попробуйте написать указанную программу без использования метода sort. Большая часть программирования - это преодоление 
сложностей, так что практикуйтесь чаще, насколько это возможно!*

И здесь я застрял :( Более-менее толковое решение, подходящее на текущий этап обучения/уровень владения языком, было найдено - сортировка пузырьком:

```
words = ["Шарик","Бобик","Барсик","Зорька","Кеша","Арчи","Мурка"]
swap = true
size = words.length - 1
while swap
    swap = false
    for i in 0...size
        swap |= words[i] > words[i + 1] 
        words[i], words[i + 1] = words[i + 1], words[i] if words[i] > words [i + 1]
    end
    size -= 1
end
puts words.join(', ')
```

Данный код работает и работает правильно. Но вот проблема - не все строки мне понятны. Кто-нибудь может детально, строчку за строчкой, как для малого дитя, рассказать, что, как и почему там выполняется?

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: А принцип сортировки пузырьком вы понимаете? Циклы? Сравнение строк? Обмен значений двух переменных? Что именно вам не понятно?

Comment: @pirj Принцип сортировки в целом ясен. Википедия благо помогла.

например, в этой части swap |= words[i] > words[i + 1] непонятно |=. Если я не ошибаюсь, то это присваивание, но почему присваивание в таком виде?

или вот здесь: words[i], words[i + 1] = words[i + 1], words[i] if words[i]
почему нельзя написать просто: words [i] = words [i + 1] ?

а еще почему, когда мы объявляем цикл while, то объявление условия выполнения цикла не обязательно? т.е. while swap и все.

Comment: @pirj
Хотелось бы получить по данному коду комментарий типа такого: есть у нас массив такой-то, своп по умолчанию(?) объявили как истина, размер получили как количество элементов массива - 1, далее у нас цикл, пока своп... ну и т.д.

Очень извиняюсь, что вопросы такие дурацкие, но не хочется просто "проглотить", потому что так надо, и сразу, не поняв до конца, переходить к другой теме изучения.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `a, b = b, a` - обмен значениями.

`while swap` - это и есть условие. Пока `swap == true` будет цикл.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Зря вы сами не писали и не разбирали алгоритм, а решили взять готовый код с недостатком знаний.

Для начала возьмем и разберемся с сортировкой и возьмем массив для примера:

```
words = ["Шарик","Бобик","Барсик","Зорька","Кеша","Арчи","Мурка"]
```

Чтобы пройтись по нему, можно использовать цикл for:

```
for i in 0...words.length 
  puts words[i]
end
```

Можно сравнивать строки с помощью обычных логических операций: `words[0] > words[1]`

Теперь пройдем циклом и попытаемся частично отсортировать наши данные с промежуточным выводом. Поскольку мы будем пользоваться конструкцией `i+1`, то чтобы не выйти за пределы массива, поменяем `words.length` на `words.length - 1`.

Для наглядности чуть изменим наш массив.

```
words = ["Яшка","Шарик","Бобик","Барсик","Зорька","Кеша","Арчи","Мурка"]

for i in 0...words.length - 1
   if words[i] > words[i+1] then
     temp = words[i]
     words[i] = words[i+1]
     words[i+1] = temp
   end
   puts words.join(","),"\n"
end
```

Вывод будет таким:

```
"Шарик","Яшка","Бобик","Барсик","Зорька","Кеша","Арчи","Мурка"
"Шарик","Бобик","Яшка","Барсик","Зорька","Кеша","Арчи","Мурка"
"Шарик","Бобик","Барсик","Яшка","Зорька","Кеша","Арчи","Мурка"
"Шарик","Бобик","Барсик","Зорька","Яшка","Кеша","Арчи","Мурка"
"Шарик","Бобик","Барсик","Зорька","Кеша","Яшка","Арчи","Мурка"
"Шарик","Бобик","Барсик","Зорька","Кеша","Арчи","Яшка","Мурка"
"Шарик","Бобик","Барсик","Зорька","Кеша","Арчи","Мурка","Яшка"
```

Как мы видим, самый маленький элемент (буква "я") пропутешествовал в конец, а другие сдвинулись к началу. Если сделать над массивом несколько таких операций, то все элементы выстроятся в отсортированный ряд.

```
for j in 0...words.length
  for i in 0...words.length - 1
   if words[i] > words[i+1] then
     temp = words[i]
     words[i] = words[i+1]
     words[i+1] = temp
     end
     puts words.join(","),"\n"
  end
end
```

В конце концов, мы получаем готовую программу сортировки пузырьком.

```
words = ["Яшка","Шарик","Бобик","Барсик","Зорька","Кеша","Арчи","Мурка"]

for j in 0...words.length - 1
  for i in 0...words.length - 1
   if words[i] > words[i+1] then
     temp = words[i]
     words[i] = words[i+1]
     words[i+1] = temp
    end
  end
end

puts words.join(","),"\n"
```

Но на самом деле этот алгоритм не идеален. Для перемены местами элементов мы используем такую конструкцию:

```
temp = words[i]
words[i] = words[i+1]
words[i+1] = temp
```

Ruby позволяет делать это проще:

```
words[i], words[i + 1] = words[i + 1], words[i]
```

К тому же у IF есть несколько вариантов синтаксиса:

```
if condition [then]
    code
end
```

и

```
code if condition
```

Во втором варианте сначала пишется один оператор и потом проверка, поэтому мы меняем наш код на аналогичный:

```
for j in 0...words.length - 1
  for i in 0...words.length - 1
    words[i], words[i + 1] = words[i + 1], words[i] if words[i] > words[i+1] 
  end
end
```

Это все один и тот же алгоритм, но записанный разными способами. Теперь разберемся с бесконечным циклом, который Вас смутил.

```
swap = false
while swap
   swap = true
end
```

Как видите, из простого примера, у нас на самом деле есть условие, это значение логической переменной swap! А теперь как оно меняется.

Есть сокращенные записи операций:

```
a = a + 1 аналогично a += 1
a = a * 1 аналогично  a *= 1
a |= true  аналогично a = a | true
```

В данном случае | является логической операцией ИЛИ которая возвращает TRUE, если хоть один из операторов содержит значение TRUE.

Данный код будет выдавать TRUE всегда, если слова не отсортированы.

```
for i in 0...words.length - 1
   swap |= words[i] > words[i + 1] 
end
```

А значит и заново запустится WHILE, если слова находятся не по порядку. А вот если они по порядку, то цикл прервется и больше не будет выполнятся. Например, для уже отсортированных слов мы пройдемся только один раз, вместо `words.length` раз, чем экономим себе время.

```
while swap
    swap = false
    for i in 0...words.length - 1
        swap |= words[i] > words[i + 1] 
        words[i], words[i + 1] = words[i + 1], words[i] if words[i] > words [i + 1]
    end
end
```

Во время просмотра сортировки видно, что последнее сортируемое слово уже на последнем месте, поэтому не обязательно проходится по всей длине массива. Отсюда получается `size`, который постоянно уменьшаем на один `size -= 1`. Вот так алгоритм получаем свой окончательный вид.

```
words = ["Шарик","Бобик","Барсик","Зорька","Кеша","Арчи","Мурка"]
swap = true
size = words.length - 1
while swap
    swap = false
    for i in 0...size
        swap |= words[i] > words[i + 1] 
        words[i], words[i + 1] = words[i + 1], words[i] if words[i] > words [i + 1]
    end
    size -= 1
end
puts words.join(', ')
```

Comment: @Alex Krass это настолько прекрасно, что у меня даже нет слов. Огромное спасибо Вам за такой подробный комментарий. Все в голове сразу по полочкам, конечно, не уложилось, но я уверен, что перечитав все еще пару раз, мне станет всё максимально понятно. Еще раз огромное спасибо! И хорошего Вам дня!

Comment: И все же (честно признаюсь, код на Rubi я вижу чуть ли не в первый раз), не лучше ли (во всех смыслах, даже в количестве буковок) писать:

     ...
     for i in 0...size
       if words[i] > words[i+1] then
         swap = true
         words[i], words[i + 1] = words[i + 1], words[i]
       end
     end
     ...

так?

Comment: @avp

`(0...size).each { |i| swap, words[i], words[i+1] = true, words[i+1], words[i] if words[i] > words[i+1] }` тогда уже.

Comment: @avp а на python видели? :) они отчасти похожи.

Безусловно, всегда можно оптимизировать, сократить, упростить, улучшить, но я просто взял пример из учебника, отсюда:
http://goo.gl/5wTya4

Comment: @avp, одно точно могу сказать, необязательное слово then рубисты всегда опускают при использовании многолайнового if. В остальном ваш вариант мне больше нравится)

--------

В однолайновом же неудобно и как-то громоздко писать if...then...end и удобнее использовать конструкцию code if condition. Тут, скорее, дело привычки и наследование философии Perl: возможность достижения одного и того же результата несколькими способами. Там даже можно использовать сишный 'condition ? statement_true : statement_false'.

    words[i] > words[i+1] ? words[i], words[i + 1] = words[i + 1], words[i] : nil

Comment: Всем спасибо!

@pirj, прямо скажу, так *совсем здорово, но непонятно* (я, например, не с первого раза заметил  true, в этом кортеже (если в Руби подобная констукция называется так)).

@Alex Krass, а `then` я из Вашего классного ответа вынес. Значит можно и без него (казалось бы можно было и догадаться, т.к. наличие `end` однозначно тут все описывает).

@vladchernik, как ни странно, но основная моя притензия: 

     swap |= words[i] > words[i + 1]

лежит в плоскости "микрооптимизации" (то же условие снова вычисляется в следующей строке). Попытка же устранения привела к более понятному коду.

Answer (score 4):

Тоже долго бился над этой задачей. Суть в том, что, до этой задачи тема циклов не проходилась в этом курсе. Поэтому долго тупил...
без циклов можно что-нибудь сделать? 
вроде бы как получилось найти "первый" элемент, и то, конечно, может неправильно в каком-нибудь случае...

```
name_unsort=['Pavel', 'Alla','Alena', 'Dick', 'Boris']  

length = name_unsort.length-1
max = name_unsort[length]

while (length-1) >= 0

 if max > name_unsort[length-1]
  max = name_unsort[length-1]
  length_max=length-1
  length=length-1
 else
  length=length-1
 end

end 

puts max 
#=>Alena
```

но потом, кажется, надо подключать рекурсию... а знаний и понимания не хватает =((

Comment: Это ответ или вопрос?

Comment: Без циклов вы ничего не сделаете, даже Ваш while в коде является циклом! Но можно сделать через два цикла while, без всякого использования for...in и рекурсии(это, кстати, тема функций, которых у Вас нет в программе). Просто for...in удобнее, но при желании спокойно заменяется аналогом while.